# Setup Git-User in Aptana

Tags: git, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 Standalone as IDE (don't blame me for that, no choice on that). As GIT client, I used eGit for quite a while, but I didn't like the menus and options there too much.

So, I wanted to give the build-in git client a chance. I like it way better, but my problem is that after I removed eGit, my username is displayed as **unknown** on all commits I make.

I didn't change anything in my options tho, I still have entries in

```
Window -> preferences -> Git -> Configuration -> User Settings

email: myname@myaddress.net
name: thisShouldBeUsedForCommitsRight
```

but it seems like the git client completely ignores those values ?

**Question**: How & where to setup git username & email for Aptana's integrated git client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a long standing bug first reported in [2010 and 2011 in this thread](http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/436-how-to-set-git-username-and-useremail), and followed in tickets like [APSTUD-4247](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4247).

Since Aptana will use a git client, make sure you hove those information setup in, for instance, msygit.

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config user.name yourName
git config user.email yourEmail
```

Comment: that did it. It needs to have the *user-* data directly in the repo-settings.